# what is the best way to get all aliases of a specific node in Kentico

Tags: kentico

Hello Kentico Experts,

What is the best way to get all aliases within a specific node in Kentico and then delete them?

E.g: I need to delete all aliases within "Products" node. There are 5000 products under this node and they may contain aliases.

How to delete them by by an easiest way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As Brenden says, there is no way of mass deletion of document aliases. You'll have to do it via SQL.

This is how you get all aliases for a sub-tree:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM [CMS_DocumentAlias]
  WHERE [AliasNodeID] IN (SELECT NodeID  FROM [CMS_Tree]
  WHERE [NodeAliasPath] LIKE '/Products/%' /*AND NodeSiteID=...*/)
```

First make a backup of your DB, then check whether the query gives you the desired records and possibly add some more constraints to the where condition (e.g. for site and culture) and when you're happy with the results just replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE`.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach without writing any code or running any SQL queries is to use the "List" view (pre v8) and "Listing" view (v8 and newer) within the Content Tree.

If you're node Products is /Products, select the Products node, then click the Listing button at the top of the content tree.  In the list mode, at the bottom of the listing, there are 2 dropdown lists. In the first one select "All pages" and in the second one, select "Delete", then click the OK button.  This will remove everything needed.

If you wish to destroy all of their history and everything, then go to the Recycle Bin and find all the pages and destroy them permanently.

Comment: Thanks @Breden for quick reply. I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough. I meant I need to delete node's alias of all nodes within a specific node.

Comment: On in this case then there isn't a mass OOTB solution.  BUT you can view all the URL aliases for the given starting path.  Go to a page and then the Properties>URLs.  Then click Add new alias.  In that dialog you can "view all aliases".  In there filter by your parent path.  Then go through and delete the aliases you don't want.   You might also (with caution) look in the `CMS_DocumentAlias` table.